# Using NEON multiply accumulate on iOS

Tags: ios, arm, neon, llvm-clang

Even though I am compiling for `armv7` only, NEON multiply-accumulate intrinsics appear to be being decomposed into separate multiplies and adds.

I've experienced this with several versions of Xcode up to the latest 4.5, with iOS SDKs 5 through 6, and with different optimisation settings, both building through Xcode and through the commandline directly.

For instance, building and disassembling some `test.cpp` containing

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

float32x4_t test( float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b, float32x4_t c )
{
   float32x4_t result = a;
   result = vmlaq_f32( result, b, c );
   return result;
}
```

with

```
clang++ -c -O3 -arch armv7 -o "test.o" test.cpp
otool -arch armv7 -tv test.o
```

results in

```
test.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
__Z4test19__simd128_float32_tS_S_:
00000000    f10d0910    add.w   r9, sp, #16 @ 0x10
00000004        46ec    mov ip, sp
00000006    ecdc2b04    vldmia  ip, {d18-d19}
0000000a    ecd90b04    vldmia  r9, {d16-d17}
0000000e    ff420df0    vmul.f32    q8, q9, q8
00000012    ec432b33    vmov    d19, r2, r3
00000016    ec410b32    vmov    d18, r0, r1
0000001a    ef400de2    vadd.f32    q8, q8, q9
0000001e    ec510b30    vmov    r0, r1, d16
00000022    ec532b31    vmov    r2, r3, d17
00000026        4770    bx  lr
```

instead of the expected use of `vmla.f32`.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: armcc or gcc produces vmla as you expect.

Comment: @auselen: that would be nice, but for a variety of reasons we don't have that option when building for iOS mobile devices :/

Comment: you can use gcc to create assembly of the algorithm you want, then use that assembly with clang :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is either a bug or an optimization by llvm-clang. armcc or gcc produces vmla as you expect but if you read *Cortex-A Series Programmer’s Guide v3*, it says:

> > **20.2.3 Scheduling**
> >
> > In some cases there can be a considerable latency, particularly VMLA multiply-accumulate (five cycles for an integer; seven cycles for a floating-point). Code using these instructions should be optimized to avoid trying to use the result value before it is ready, otherwise a stall will occur. Despite having a few cycles result latency, these instructions do fully pipeline so several
> >     operations can be in flight at once.

So it makes sense for llvm-clang to separate vmla into multiply and accumulate to fill the pipeline.

Comment: Hm, didn't realise it was 7 cycles on this architecture. Will get hold of the Cortex-A guide instead of relying on obsolete knowledge.

Comment: I think that's cpu dependent instead of architecture. So it can be different between A8 or A9. Please feel free to update my answer if you think those cycle numbers are misleading in some way. I personally never rely on those cycle numbers since I'm not working on some specific processor library like decoding video. I guess those kind of work requires a lot of fine detailing, but in generic programming that doesn't add too much value. Of course it is good to know how to interleave instructions among processing units...

Comment: Cycle-timings are micro-architecture dependent, and so vary between implementations of the armv7 architecture.  `clang` is reluctant to emit `vmla.f32`, because the situations in which it is a performance win are relatively limited on current implementations of the architecture (it would likely slow down the code in question here, for example).  That said, it definitely will emit the instruction when its performance model predicts it to be beneficial.

Comment: @auselen, I see considerable stalling in case of VPADAL(pairwise add and accumulate long) too, when I have a sequence of VPADAL and each one waiting on the result of before. But the programmers guide doesn't specifically state about this instruction as compared to the VMLA. So, may be this reason quoted by you may be the cause for the huge stall?

Comment: @nguns yes. I believe it is true for any not ready register depending instruction. with some instructions it will be fast, with some it will be slower. try to separate the dependency between register usage. for example instead of "for (..) { a += x[i] } do "for (..) {a += x[i]; b += x[i+1]} a += b;" compiler should get this kind of vectorization for you if you set your code in the right way and if it is recent enough.

Comment: +1'ed, yup that is the solution at work now, but the consecutive 'vpadal' instructions have to be sufficiently spaced(around four instructions) or have to use four independent registers as destination registers and then add them out of the loop as suggested if we wish not to see any stall.

Comment: @nguns Did you see any compiler producing such code? I didn't get any to try it.

Comment: @auselen I'm directly coding in assembly, so din't happen to see it. But seems to be a good exercise to try out, will update you if I get to work this out.

Answer (score 1):

Neon multiply-add instructions perform the operation

```
c = c + a * b
```

Note that the destination and one of the sources is the same. If you want to perform the operation

```
d = c + a * b
```

the compiler will have to decompose it into two instructions

```
d = c
d = d + a * b
```

Alternative, it can decompose it into multiply + add instructions

```
d = a * b
d = d + c
```

On Cortex-A8/A9 both variants have the same throughput, but on Cortex-A8 the second variant has lower latency, because multiply-add instruction causes stalls in many situations.

Comment: I would have liked to see first expression as "c += a * b". I think intrinsic for vmla/s and its documentation is misleading.

Comment: Note that `result = result + a * b` is exactly the example I give performs! I could just about convince myself the optimiser is ignoring the intrinsic I specified and making some kind of transformation based on register colouring as you describe, except (a) this happens at all optimisation levels - including -O0; (b) this happens *everywhere*, including code performing much heavier processing than the simple example I give where the result is clearly obviously worse than if MLAs had been used (e.g. in code performing 4x4 matrix/matrix multiplication) - MLA is literally never generated.

Comment: @Maratyszcza: I have placed a more complex sample [here](http://www.toothycat.net/~sham/mlaq_for_so.html), hopefully this demonstrates that whatever is happening here, it is not the optimisation you describe

Comment: @moonshadow does anything change if you remove the "result =" part from intrinsic call like "vmlaq_f32( result, b, c );" and also if you eliminate "result" completely and "return a;" when finished?

Comment: @auselen: since the intrinsics are declared as taking their arguments by value, they cannot affect them; thus, removing the "`result =`" part causes the compiler realise the function is equivalent to "`return a`" and simply optimise the body away entirely. Removing `result` and assigning to `a` yields exactly the same code as before.

Comment: @moonshadow do you know any document laying out the semantics of those intrinsics? vmla have to modify c for sure (in case result = vmla(c, a, b)), but   I don't understand what 'result' mean, c or a copy of c?